# Sum up columns and divide them by adjacent cell FOR THE MOST RECENT THREE ROWS

Tags: r, dplyr

I asked a similar question a few days back, but wanted to update it. How would I sum up columns and divide them by adjacent cell for the most recent three rows? For example, if I had the dataset:
I have the following table:

| Date | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/10/2021 | 20 | 25 | 25 | 26 | 26 | 25 | 31 |
| 08/10/2021 | 26 | 25 | 25 | 26 | 25 | 31 |  |
| 09/10/2021 | 29 | 29 | 25 | 26 | 39 |  |  |
| 10/10/2021 | 20 | 29 | 25 | 31 |  |  |  |
| 11/10/2021 | 20 | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |  |
| 12/10/2021 | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/10/2022 | 39 |  |  |  |  |  |  |

```html
## example data d:
d <- 
structure(list(Date = c("07.10.2021", "08.10.2021", "09.10.2021", 
"10.10.2021", "11.10.2021", "12.10.2021", "01.10.2022"), X1 = c(20L, 
26L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 39L), X2 = c(25L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 
30L, NA), X3 = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 30L, NA, NA), X4 = c(26L, 
26L, 26L, 31L, NA, NA, NA), X5 = c(26L, 25L, 39L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA), X6 = c(25L, 31L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(31L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 7L))
```

I'm trying to add up the columns, but only up to the column that has an adjacent cell, and then ONLY UP TO THREE VALUES FROM THE BOTTOM CELL FOR EACH RESPECTIVE COLUMN. I then am trying to divide each sum by the previous sum. For example, column 1 and 2 would add down to 12/10/2021 and then column 2 would be divided by column 1. The output would be the table plus a row with the total values under each of the columns, as shown below:

| Date | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 07/10/2021 | 20 | 25 | 25 | 26 | 26 | 25 | 31 |
| 08/10/2021 | 26 | 25 | 25 | 26 | 25 | 31 |  |
| 09/10/2021 | 29 | 29 | 25 | 26 | 39 |  |  |
| 10/10/2021 | 20 | 29 | 25 | 31 |  |  |  |
| 11/10/2021 | 20 | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |  |
| 12/10/2021 | 30 | 30 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 1/10/2022 | 39 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| TOTAL | 1 | 1.27 | 0.90 | 1.18 | 1.15 | 1.09 | 1.24 |

I am trying to modify this code to do so:

```html
(d[,8:3] |> apply(2, cumsum)/
 d[,7:2] |> apply(2, cumsum)
) |>
  diag() |>
  rev()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use this simple `sapply`.

Up front, I think your `1.18` should instead be

```r
(26+26+31)/(25+25+25)
# [1] 1.106667
```

Code:

```r
tmp <- as.data.frame(matrix(c(1, sapply(3:ncol(d), function(ci) {
  ri <- tail(which(!is.na(d[[ci]])), n = 3)
  sum(d[[ci]][ri]) / sum(d[[ci-1]][ri])
})), nrow = 1))
rbind(d, cbind(data.frame(Date="Total"), setNames(tmp, names(d)[-1])))
#         Date X1        X2         X3        X4        X5        X6    X7
# 1 07.10.2021 20 25.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 26.000000 25.000000 31.00
# 2 08.10.2021 26 25.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 25.000000 31.000000    NA
# 3 09.10.2021 29 29.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 39.000000        NA    NA
# 4 10.10.2021 20 29.000000 25.0000000 31.000000        NA        NA    NA
# 5 11.10.2021 20 30.000000 30.0000000        NA        NA        NA    NA
# 6 12.10.2021 30 30.000000         NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
# 7 01.10.2022 39        NA         NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
# 8      Total  1  1.271429  0.9090909  1.106667  1.153846  1.098039  1.24
```

In native-pipe speak, it can be (somewhat) spread out as:

```r
fun <- function(ci) {
  ri <- tail(which(!is.na(d[[ci]])), n = 3)
  sum(d[[ci]][ri]) / sum(d[[ci-1]][ri])
}
tmp <- c(1, sapply(3:ncol(d), fun)) |>
  matrix(nrow = 1) |>
  `colnames<-`(names(d)[-1])
tmp
#      X1       X2        X3       X4       X5       X6   X7
# [1,]  1 1.271429 0.9090909 1.106667 1.153846 1.098039 1.24
out <- data.frame(Date = "Total") |>
  cbind(tmp) |>
  (\(z) rbind(d, z))()
out
#         Date X1        X2         X3        X4        X5        X6    X7
# 1 07.10.2021 20 25.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 26.000000 25.000000 31.00
# 2 08.10.2021 26 25.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 25.000000 31.000000    NA
# 3 09.10.2021 29 29.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 39.000000        NA    NA
# 4 10.10.2021 20 29.000000 25.0000000 31.000000        NA        NA    NA
# 5 11.10.2021 20 30.000000 30.0000000        NA        NA        NA    NA
# 6 12.10.2021 30 30.000000         NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
# 7 01.10.2022 39        NA         NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
# 8      Total  1  1.271429  0.9090909  1.106667  1.153846  1.098039  1.24
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this in Tidyverse or similar to what I did? I'm getting the error: Error in sum(manipulated_data[[ci - 1]][ri]) : 
  invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: What do you mean _"similar to what I did"_? All of your code is base R and you didn't tag [tag:dplyr] or similar. If you want/need it to be in a particular dialect of R, you really need to specify that. Perhaps the reason two answers have been provided that aren't similar to what you did because it may not be the best approach.

Comment: I added the dplyr tag. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: Anyways, I fixed the error. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

d <-
  structure(list(Date = c(
    "07.10.2021", "08.10.2021", "09.10.2021",
    "10.10.2021", "11.10.2021", "12.10.2021", "01.10.2022"
  ), X1 = c(
    20L,
    26L, 29L, 20L, 20L, 30L, 39L
  ), X2 = c(
    25L, 25L, 29L, 29L, 30L,
    30L, NA
  ), X3 = c(25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 30L, NA, NA), X4 = c(
    26L,
    26L, 26L, 31L, NA, NA, NA
  ), X5 = c(
    26L, 25L, 39L, NA, NA, NA,
    NA
  ), X6 = c(25L, 31L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), X7 = c(
    31L, NA, NA,
    NA, NA, NA, NA
  )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 7L))


(nd <- names(d))
(ndx <- nd[startsWith(nd, "X")])
(ndx1 <- c(ndx[1], na.omit(dplyr::lag(ndx, 1))))

(result_row <- map2_dbl(ndx, ndx1, \(calc_col, prev_col){
  lc <- length(na.omit(d[[calc_col]]))
  prev_3 <- sum(tail(head(d[[prev_col]], lc), n = 3))
  calc_3 <- sum(tail(head(d[[calc_col]], lc), n = 3))
  calc_3 / prev_3
}))

names(result_row) <- ndx
bind_cols(
  tibble(Date = "Total"),
  enframe(result_row) |> pivot_wider()
)
d |> bind_rows(
  bind_cols(
    tibble(Date = "Total"),
    enframe(result_row) |> pivot_wider()
  )
)
```

```
        Date X1        X2         X3        X4        X5        X6    X7
1 07.10.2021 20 25.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 26.000000 25.000000 31.00
2 08.10.2021 26 25.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 25.000000 31.000000    NA
3 09.10.2021 29 29.000000 25.0000000 26.000000 39.000000        NA    NA
4 10.10.2021 20 29.000000 25.0000000 31.000000        NA        NA    NA
5 11.10.2021 20 30.000000 30.0000000        NA        NA        NA    NA
6 12.10.2021 30 30.000000         NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
7 01.10.2022 39        NA         NA        NA        NA        NA    NA
8      Total  1  1.271429  0.9090909  1.106667  1.153846  1.098039  1.24
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to do this similar to what I did?

Comment: My way makes sense to me,  I suppose your style could be done by some metapgrogramming, but I'm sceptical of the benefits and the disadvantages are hard to understand code